# Compatibility of HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 2645 All-in-One Printer with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, printing

I preferred to buy [HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 2645 All-in-One Printer](http://www.flipkart.com/hp-deskjet-ink-advantage-2645-all-in-one-printer/p/itmdxph4dpbw7jtd?pid=PRNDXPH268F5NKHT) from flipkart. This one is a ink advantage printer with many facilities like Print, Copy, Scan & Fax.

The basic System requirement for this printer is as follows

`Operating System`  Windows: XP (32-bit, SP3), Vista, 7, 8, Mac OS X: v10.6, Lion, Mountain Lion

`Hard Drive`    Windows 7 and 8: 2 GB Free Hard Disk Space, Windows Vista - 2 GB Free Hard Disk Space, Windows XP (32-bit SP3) - 750 MB Free Hard Disk Space, Mac OS X v10.6, OS X Lion, OS X Mountain Lion - 1 GB Free Hard Disk Space

`Processor` Windows 7 and Windows 8: 1 GHz Processor, Windows Vista: 800 MHz Processor, Windows XP (32-bit, SP3): Intel Pentium II, Celeron Processor, 233 MHz Processor, Mac OS X v10.6 - Intel Core Processor, OS X Lion - Intel Core Processor, OS X Mountain Lion - Intel Core Processor

`Other System Requirements` Internet Connection, Internet Explorer 6 or Higher, CD-ROM, DVD Drive, USB Port

The output of `lshw -class processor` which gives the information about my processor

```
 *-cpu:0 DISABLED        
       description: CPU [empty]
       product: (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
       physical id: 4
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: CPU 1
  *-cpu:1
       product: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5500  @ 2.80GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: 6.7.10
       serial: 0001-067A-0000-0000-0000-0000
       size: 2800MHz
       capacity: 2800MHz
       width: 64 bits
       capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority cpufreq
       configuration: id=0
     *-logicalcpu:0
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 0.1
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: logical
     *-logicalcpu:1
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 0.2
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: logical
  *-cpu:2
       physical id: 2
       bus info: cpu@1
       version: 6.7.10
       serial: 0001-067A-0000-0000-0000-0000
       size: 1200MHz
       capacity: 1200MHz
       capabilities: vmx ht cpufreq
       configuration: id=0
     *-logicalcpu:0
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 0.1
          capabilities: logical
     *-logicalcpu:1
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 0.2
          capabilities: logical
```

and the output of hdparm -I /dev/sda is as follows gives information about my hardrive

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST500DM002-1BD142                       
    Serial Number:      W2A1MGAL
    Firmware Revision:  KC48    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  976773168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = 16384 KBytes
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 208
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Read/Write Long (AC1), obsolete
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    82min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 82min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c5003cdc1714
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 03cdc1714
Checksum: correct
```

I believe my computer hardware is compatible with this printer, but I'm using Ubuntu gnome 14.04 and I'm unsure whether this is compatible.

Comment: Often best to download newest hplip from HP. Ubuntu 14.04 supplies HPLIP 3.11.5 by default and copy in the repository does not have all the newest features. Go here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Comment: @oldfred Post your comment as answer.

Comment: @AUmarMukthar: Did the printer work with Ubuntu 14.04? Just wish the thing had wireless like the 4625 but in SL we are out of stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HP and newer printers best to install newest HPLIP directly from HP. There is a version of HPLIP in Ubuntu repository but it usually is older and does not support newest printers or features.

You can get a Linux installer script directly from HP. Supports most Linux including Ubuntu and all its printers. Details in link on what exactly is supported.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

When you run it, it creates lots of files & folders. Better to copy into its own folder, not just leave in Downloads.

If you get the no system tray error you can do this. I have always just ignored it after a reboot.
No system tray error:
open up the "startup applications" editor from the admin menu.
add a new program, for the command put:
sleep 10;/usr/bin/hp-systray

Answer (score 1):

According to http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html your HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 2645 All-in-one Printer printer should be supported in Ubuntu 14.04 with the deskjet_2640_series driver.

```
$ lsb_release -dr
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
$ LANG=C apt-cache policy hplip
hplip:
  Installed: 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2
$ lpinfo -m | grep 2640
drv:///hpcups.drv/hp-deskjet_2640_series.ppd HP Deskjet 2640 Series, hpcups 3.14.3
```

Please try the above driver.